# Finding convergence of integration $\int^{1}_{0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x-x^3}dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

> Finding convergence of integration $$\int^{1}_{0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x-x^3}dx$$

What i try
$$1<2+\cos x<3$$

$$\Longrightarrow \int^{1}_{0}\frac{1}{x-x^3}dx<\int^{1}_{0}\frac{2+\cos x}{x-x^3}<\int^{1}_{0}\frac{3}{x-x^3}dx$$

using by parts is very complex.

How do i solve it. Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} \frac {2+\cos x} {x-x^{3}} dx \geq \int_0^{1} \frac 1 {x(1-x^{2})} dx\geq\int_0^{1} \frac 1 x dx =\infty$